# Subclass and using UIActivityItemProvider with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sharing

I finally find someone who was facing the same problem than me.

[UIActivityViewController customize text based on selected activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639982/uiactivityviewcontroller-customize-text-based-on-selected-activity)

I want to customize the content share with the activities of the UIActivityViewController. The good answer is the following:

> "Instead of passing the text strings into the initWithActivityItems
>   call, pass in your own sub-class of the UIActivityItemProvider class
>   and when you implement the itemForActivityType method it will provide
>   the sharing service as the 'activityType' parameter.
>
> You can then return the customized content from this method."

I understand tricks, but I'm not getting the way to do it...

I did this as a subclass:

```
@interface SharingItems : UIActivityItemProvider

@implementation SharingItems

-(id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
{
    // Here depending on the activityType i want to share NSString or UIImage
}

@end
```

But I don't know what to do now in my original viewController:

```
-(void)actionSheet
{    
    if ([[UIActivityViewController class] respondsToSelector:@selector(alloc)])
    {
        __block NSString *imgName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", _sharingUrl];
        NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:imgName, nil];

        UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
        [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];

        __block NSString *chan      = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", _channel];
        [activityController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString* activityType, BOOL completed)
        {
            if (completed)
            {
            }
        }];
    }
    else
        [self displayActionSheet];
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Here's an example UIActivityItemProvider (not tested but adapted from working code):

```
@implementation StringProvider

- (id)initWithPlaceholderString:(NSString*)placeholder facebookString:(NSString*)facebookString
{
    self = [super initWithPlaceholderItem:placeholder];
    if (self) {
        _facebookString = facebookString;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)item
{
    if ([self.activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]) {
        return _facebookString;
    } else {
        return self.placeholderItem;
    }
}

@end
```

Then when you set up the activity view controller:

```
StringProvider *stringProvider = [[StringProvider alloc] initWithPlaceholderString:@"Default string" facebookString:@"Hello, Facebook."];
UIActivityViewController *shareController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[stringProvider] applicationActivities:nil];
```

Basically you create UIActivityItemProviders that provide the right data when the -(id)item method is called and pass in those activity item providers when you create the activity view controller.  You need to initialize with a placeholder item so the OS knows what class the final item will be (most likely NSString, NSURL, UIImage). Hope that helps!

Comment: How do you return multiple images/videos through this `item` method?