# How to do Sharing Different text in Facebook and Twitter using UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

In my application I used `UIActivityViewController` to share text in *Facebook* and *Twitter*. But how to do different text to share? please help ..thanks in advance

I used this code:

```
NSString *posturl2=@"twittwrer and facebook ";


UISimpleTextPrintFormatter *printData = [[UISimpleTextPrintFormatter alloc]
                                             initWithText:@"Hi"];


NSArray *Itemsarray = @[posturl2,printData];

UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:Itemsarray                                                                              applicationActivities:nil];


[self presentViewController:activityController
                       animated:YES completion:nil];
```

want like this

[image]

Comment: use social.frmaework for this

Comment: but i want visual as default for ios

Comment: Since Social.Framework IS included in iOS, it's a "default" feature.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639982/uiactivityviewcontroller-customize-text-based-on-selected-activity ?

Answer (score -2):

Import Social Framework

```
#import <Social/Social.h>
```

Then just call

```
- (void)shareOnFacebookWithText:(NSString *)textToShare {
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        [controller setInitialText:textToShare];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)shareOnTwitterWithText:(NSString *)textToShare {

    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {
        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                               composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:textToShare];
        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: i know it..but i want like photo above